# Trouble with unique formula and matching criteria from multiple columns and sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-query-language, textjoin

My sheet has an agent count page that displays the names and how many times an agents name is on both sheets "IAD(Tampa)" and "Archive Docs".

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({'IAD(Tampa)'!D3:D; 'Archived Docs'!D3:D},))
=COUNTIF('Archived Docs'!D3:D,A:A) + COUNTIF('IAD(Tampa)'!D3:D,A:A)
```

The ask is this. How can I do the above if column "H" and "Match A3:A12" are a match?
Example would be DO NOT count Jesse when column "H" is Daniel because this NOT a match.
Column "A" should be the name and column "B" should be the count.

SAMPLE SHEET https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1befqsGQvbPfn0XTGrygLOGcrUIMrICUagJVH0S-2rDw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({'IAD(Tampa)'!D3:H; 'Archived Docs'!D3:H}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col5 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Match!A2:A12)&"' 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''", )
```

Comment: Is there a way to add to this formula so I am only querying for current month? Both of my sheets IAD(Tampa) and Archived Docs have a timestamp in column A

Comment: @JonBeckner try: `=QUERY({'IAD(Tampa)'!D3:H; 'Archived Docs'!D3:H}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col5 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Match!A2:A12)&"' 
  and month(Col1)+1 = "&MONTH(TODAY())&"
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''", )`

Comment: I get an error. See sample sheet for exact error.. My query sheets have the date in column 1 not sheet with this formula

Comment: which sheet is col1 referencing? "Agent count" or another sheet?

Comment: @JonBeckner use: `=QUERY({'IAD(Tampa)'!A3:H; 'Archived Docs'!A3:H},   "select Col4,count(Col4)    where Col8 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Match!A2:A12)&"'    and month(Col1)+1 = "&MONTH(TODAY())&"   group by Col4    label count(Col4)''", )` and see your Agent sheet

Comment: perfectly done.

Comment: If I wanted to remove the count from the query and just keep the names how might I do that? I am trying to better understand this formula.

Comment: @JonBeckner use: `=INDEX(QUERY({'IAD(Tampa)'!A3:H; 'Archived Docs'!A3:H},   "select Col4,count(Col4)    where Col8 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Match!A2:A12)&"'    and month(Col1)+1 = "&MONTH(TODAY())&"   group by Col4    label count(Col4)''", ),,1)`